# Selenium htmlsuite parallel execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

Is it possible for parallel execution of Selenium recorded HTML test case or html suite.  Is it possible through JUnit or TestNG or Ant?

I have looked everywhere for days but did not find anything. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to run the recorded scripts in Grid without doing any changes.

If you are okay to do changes, read below.

Assuming that you used Selenium FireFox IDE plugin to record test cases...

- Export your recorded scripts to appropriate(junit) version using the IDE menu option
- Change the usage to RemoteWebDriver
- Configure jUnit (proper installations required)
- Setup Grid with jUnit (lot of documents available)

Not clear? Please do a Google search :)

http://blicksplitter.wordpress.com/running-selenium-grid2-tests-in-parallel/

http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/10/parallel-junit-4-and-selenium-part-three-parallelism-and-ondemand/

Comment: how want to run the script html format. dont want to convert it into junit format

Comment: even if i exported as junit format. I think its difficult for parallel execution unless I edit in thr recorded script. Im looking for a way to run the recorded script parallely without making any change in it.

Answer (score 0):

## Command Line Version

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you execute your tests via command line like such(You need to navigate to the folder where your selenium JAR is located for this to work):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -userExtensions "C:\UITests\user-extensions.js" -port 4444 -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://appURLHere" "C:\UITests\TestSuite.html" "C:\UITests\TestResults.html" -timeout 1800 -avoidProxy
```

Then you should be able to launch at the same time using the same JAR another instance of the test runner simply using another port, like such:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -userExtensions "C:\UITests\user-extensions.js" -port 5555 -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://appURLHere" "C:\UITests\TestSuite.html" "C:\UITests\TestResults.html" -timeout 1800 -avoidProxy
```

## Ant Version

This could be done via ant and would look something like this:

```
<parallel>
 <java jar="${testDependencies}\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar" fork="true">
    <arg line="-userExtensions &quot;${testDependencies}\user-extensions.js&quot;"/>
    <arg line="-port 4444"/>
    <arg line="-htmlSuite &quot;*firefox ${firefox}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${appURL}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${suite.file}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${report.name}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="-timeout ${timeout}"/>
    <arg line="-avoidProxy"/>
 </java> 

 <java jar="${testDependencies}\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar" fork="true">
    <arg line="-userExtensions &quot;${testDependencies}\user-extensions.js&quot;"/>
    <arg line="-port 5555"/>
    <arg line="-htmlSuite &quot;*firefox ${firefox}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${appURL}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${suite.file}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="&quot;${report.name}&quot;"/>
    <arg line="-timeout ${timeout}"/>
    <arg line="-avoidProxy"/>
 </java> 
</parallel>
```

Hope this helps clarify this a little bit!